# Blogger custom archive gadget, posts list not show

Tags: blogger

I want create list post per years on archive gadget, i success for showing years and month but posts list not showing.

```
<b:loop values='data:data' var='d'>
    <a expr:href='data:d.url'><data:d.name/></a>
    <b:loop values='data:d.posts' var='post'>
        <a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
    </b:loop>
</b:loop>
```

I'm trying loop `data:posts`, `data:d.data.posts` with no luck. I want display archive gadget like this:

```
<!-- year -->
<a href='http://dummybloq.blogspot.com/2017'>2017</a>
  <!-- And here post list -->
  <a href='https://dummybloq.blogspot.com/2017/12.html'>titleof post</a>
```

How to show posts list inside archive gadget?!

Comment: Can you give some more context? I don't really know what you are going for. This code is in which widget, archive or an other? How does the desired output look like? how does it look like now?

Comment: The widget look just show links of year `<a href='https://dummybloq.blogspot.com/2017/>2017</a>`.. I want display post per years like hierarchy style..

Comment: All the data for post titles is not present in the post loop that archive widget provides. Other than the current month, all the post titles for other months/years are loaded in via an AJAX request when a particular day/month/year is expanded (For example if you want to see the post title for a full year, then the archive widget makes the following AJAX request - https://webmasters.googleblog.com/?action=getTitles&widgetId=BlogArchive1&widgetType=BlogArchive&responseType=js&path=https%3A%2F%2Fwebmasters.googleblog.com%2F2017%2F (This is fetching all post titles for 2017 for Webmaster Blog))

Comment: How to show it?! And i also see `data:posts` loop inside the xml file, for what data it is? It's in `<b:includable id='posts' var='posts'>` in archive widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answer my own question, first make sure to enable show post/entry list on widget settings menu, and this code for show post list

```
<!-- years loop -->
<b:loop values='data:data' var='data'>
    <a expr:href='data:data.url'><data:data.name/></a>
    <!-- month loop, and i dont use it -->
    <b:loop values='data:data.data' var='d'>
        <!-- posts loop -->
        <b:loop values='data:d.posts' var='post'>
            <a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
        </b:loop>
    </b:loop>
</b:loop>
```

Thanks for your response guys..

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE:*** after some tinkering, in the Archive Gadget, you could loop like this through the items, to construct your hierarchy:

```
<b:loop values='data:this.data' var='year'>
    <ul class='hierarchy'>
        <li>
            <data:year.name/>
            <ul>
                <b:loop values='data:year.data' var='month'>
                    <li>
                        <data:month.name/> -- 
                        <data:month.url/>
                    </li>
                </b:loop>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</b:loop>
```

---

### Old Answer: customizing a standard Theme

Maybe I misunderstood, but this should work with the default features of blogger.com, at least with the Theme Contempo

1) first open the Gadget properties

[image: Screenshot Blogger Backend]

2) the set the correct values and save

[image: Screenshot Blogger Backend, Archive Properties]

3) Now see the result

[image: Screenshot Blogger Contempo Archive Gadget Layout]

Comment: Can you show the template code of the archive gadget?! I'm creating template from stracth and write own html markup for change blogger default markup..

Can you show what avaiable data from archive gadget?! Please?!

Comment: @FajarFRamdhan as stated in my answer I'm using the *standard Theme Contempo*, **no code alterations**. the problem is, that the new themes use some `include`s with the name `super.main` or so, where I assume that it invokes some _parent include_ , but the code cannot be found in the xml. ... the documentation available is very limited. so how the data is access and from which properties is a mystery.

Comment: Ah! That the reason i'm asking here, to find out about `super` which can't be found anywhere, other widget i can learn and write with success, i'm just confussed with this archive widget.. Maybe i will just use standard widget.. Thanks for your answer..

Comment: @FajarFRamdhan, I updated my answer this should work.

Comment: Thanks, its more clear than use `data:data.data` for showing years and month.