# Posts not displaying in archive widget blogger

Tags: blogger

for some reason, only the posts for the month of March are displaying in my archive page. I'd like all the post titles to be displyed under each month. (see picture 1)

[image]

Notice that if I change the order of display (older first) it gives the same problem but for the month of July

[image]

Here is the current code of the ArchiveBlog2 widget that i'm using

```
<b:widget id='BlogArchive2' locked='false' title='Archive' type='BlogArchive' version='2' visible='true'>
              <b:widget-settings>
                <b:widget-setting name='showStyle'>HIERARCHY</b:widget-setting>
                <b:widget-setting name='yearPattern'>yyyy</b:widget-setting>
                <b:widget-setting name='showWeekEnd'>true</b:widget-setting>
                <b:widget-setting name='monthPattern'>MMMM</b:widget-setting>
                <b:widget-setting name='dayPattern'>MMM dd</b:widget-setting>
                <b:widget-setting name='weekPattern'>MM/dd</b:widget-setting>
                <b:widget-setting name='chronological'>false</b:widget-setting>
                <b:widget-setting name='showPosts'>true</b:widget-setting>
                <b:widget-setting name='frequency'>MONTHLY</b:widget-setting>
              </b:widget-settings>
              <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
                <details class='collapsible extendable' open='open'>
                  <b:attr name='open' value='open'/>
                  <b:with value='true' var='renderAsDetails'>
                    <b:with value='data:messages.archive' var='defaultTitle'>
                      <b:include name='super.main'/>
                    </b:with>
                  </b:with>
                </details>
              </b:includable>
              <b:includable id='content'>
                <div class='widget-content'>
                  <div id='ArchiveList'>
                    <div expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_ArchiveList&quot;'>
                      <b:include cond='data:this.style == &quot;HIERARCHY&quot;' name='hierarchy'/>
                      <b:include cond='data:this.style in {&quot;FLAT&quot;, &quot;MENU&quot;}' name='flat'/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </b:includable>
              <b:includable id='flat'>
                <b:include data='{buttonClass: &quot;pill-button&quot;,items: data:this.data,itemSet: &quot;data&quot;,itemsMarkup: &quot;super.flat&quot;}' name='extendableItems'/>
              </b:includable>
              <b:includable id='hierarchy'>
                <b:include data='{buttonClass: &quot;pill-button&quot;,limit: 1,items: data:this.data,itemSet: &quot;data&quot;,itemsMarkup: &quot;super.hierarchy&quot;}' name='extendableItems'/>
              </b:includable>
              <b:includable id='interval' var='intervals'>
                <ul class='hierarchy'>
                                        <!-- Loop intervals -->
                  <b:loop values='data:intervals' var='interval'>
                    <li class='archivedate'>
                      <div class='hierarchy-title'>
                        <a class='post-count-link' expr:href='data:interval.url'>
                          <data:interval.name/>
                          <span class='post-count'>
                            <data:interval.post-count/>
                          </span>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class='hierarchy-content'>
                        <b:include cond='data:interval.data' data='interval.data' name='interval'/>
                        <b:include cond='data:interval.posts' data='interval.posts' name='posts'/>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </b:loop>
                </ul>
              </b:includable>
              <b:includable id='posts' var='posts'>
                <ul class='posts hierarchy'>
                                        <!-- Loop Post -->
                  <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
                    <li>
                      <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
                        <data:post.title/>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </b:loop>
                </ul>
              </b:includable>
            </b:widget>
```

the webpage is here [jayasaro.blogspot.com/p/archive.html](https://jayasaro.blogspot.com/p/archive.html). All the links of the Archive works well and directs to the correct months etc.

Thanks for your help.

This might be [a helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908277/blogger-custom-archive-gadget-posts-list-not-show) but I was not able to use that code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a code for the widget BlogArchive that display title in a older template for blogspot blog. here is the code (make sure to give it the good ID, for me blogarchive2 and you may need to play with css a bit  :

```
<b:widget id='BlogArchive1' locked='false' title='' type='BlogArchive'>
    <b:widget-settings>
      <b:widget-setting name='showStyle'>HIERARCHY</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='yearPattern'>yyyy</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showWeekEnd'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='monthPattern'>MMMM yyyy</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='dayPattern'>MMM dd</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='weekPattern'>MM/dd</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='chronological'>false</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='showPosts'>true</b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='frequency'>MONTHLY</b:widget-setting>
    </b:widget-settings>
    <b:includable id='main'>
  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
    <h2><data:title/></h2>
  </b:if>
  <div class='widget-content'>
  <div id='ArchiveList'>
  <div expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_ArchiveList&quot;'>
    <b:include cond='data:style == &quot;HIERARCHY&quot;' data='data' name='interval'/>
    <b:include cond='data:style == &quot;FLAT&quot;' data='data' name='flat'/>
    <b:include cond='data:style == &quot;MENU&quot;' data='data' name='menu'/>
  </div>
  </div>
  <b:include name='quickedit'/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
    <b:includable id='flat' var='data'>
  <ul class='flat'>
    <b:loop values='data:data' var='i'>
      <li class='archivedate'>
        <a expr:href='data:i.url'><data:i.name/></a> (<data:i.post-count/>)
      </li>
    </b:loop>
  </ul>
</b:includable>
    <b:includable id='interval' var='intervalData'>
  <b:loop values='data:intervalData' var='interval'>
    <ul class='hierarchy'>
      <li expr:class='&quot;archivedate &quot; + data:interval.expclass'>
        <b:include cond='data:interval.toggleId' data='interval' name='toggle'/>
        <a class='post-count-link' expr:href='data:interval.url'>
          <data:interval.name/>
        </a>
        <span class='post-count' dir='ltr'>(<data:interval.post-count/>)</span>
        <b:include cond='data:interval.data' data='interval.data' name='interval'/>
        <b:include cond='data:interval.posts' data='interval.posts' name='posts'/>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </b:loop>
</b:includable>
    <b:includable id='menu' var='data'>
  <select expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_ArchiveMenu&quot;'>
    <option value=''><data:title/></option>
    <b:loop values='data:data' var='i'>
      <option expr:value='data:i.url'><data:i.name/> (<data:i.post-count/>)</option>
    </b:loop>
  </select>
</b:includable>
    <b:includable id='posts' var='posts'>
  <ul class='posts'>
    <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
      <li><a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a></li>
    </b:loop>
  </ul>
</b:includable>
    <b:includable id='toggle' var='interval'>
  <a class='toggle' href='javascript:void(0)'>
    <span expr:class='&quot;zippy&quot; + (data:interval.expclass == &quot;expanded&quot; ? &quot; toggle-open&quot; : &quot;&quot;)'>
      <b:if cond='data:interval.expclass == &quot;expanded&quot;'>
        &#9660;&#160;
      <b:elseif cond='data:blog.languageDirection == &quot;rtl&quot;'/>
        &#9668;&#160;
      <b:else/>
        &#9658;&#160;
      </b:if>
    </span>
  </a>
</b:includable>
  </b:widget>
```

[image]